# Making full text search with Postgresql and hibernate - missing type for tsvector and operator @@

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, full-text-search, criteria-api

I have postgresql database where I'd like to run full text search queries by using JPA/Hibernate criteria API. My issue is that I don't know which type should I use for tsvector type and what is a replacement for @@ operator?

I created a database view which combines data from two tables and makes a concatenated tsvector:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW node_name_description_tags AS
    SELECT nodeId, document
    FROM (SELECT node.id as nodeId,
                 to_tsvector('english', node.name) || 
                 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(node.description, ' ')) ||
                 to_tsvector('english', coalesce(string_agg(tag.name, ' '), ' '))  as document
          FROM node
          JOIN tag_node ON node.id = tag_node.node_id
          JOIN tag ON tag.id = tag_node.tag_id
          GROUP BY nodeId) as documents
```

Then I can run queries on it like this and it returns what I expect:

```sql
SELECT * FROM node_name_description_tags WHERE document @@ PLAINTO_TSQUERY('english', 'integration user administration file')
```

What I was going to do next - create hibernate entity mapped to this view, but I don't know which type to use for column tsvector. Then I was going to to create a hibernate specification with where clause, but I don't know how operator @@ is implemented in hibernate. It seems that this functionality isn't supported at all!

I found on the internet that people propose to use custom dialect with added full-text-search function which generates @@ where clause. That's, basically, everything what I have now.

Any advice on how to make this working from Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't want to make a full text search across all the fields. As a quick as working solution I added custom column, search queries to be run accordingly to:

`@Column(name = "full_text_search_index", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)`

In this column I store and keep consistent (on entity updates) needed fields for search (some kind of denormalization), then search queries just run in 'contains' like mode. This column is indexes, so it is working quite good.